# Encryptions together with HTTPS

Tags: security, encryption, https

I would like to know if I am using HTTPS for client(e.g a iOS App) to communicate with a server to exchange data, then the "custom encryption" part in my following flow is unnecessary? Because, as I know, using HTTPS protocol already has the encryption functionality included.

In client
plaintext -> custom encryption -> https ---------> server

Answer (score 0):

What does HTTPS protocol do is to secure the transport layer prior to exchange of messages (HTTP). What does it mean? It means to say that you are only communicating to your server and client securely and only the two of them can interpret the messages.

> then the "custom encryption" part in my following flow is unnecessary?

To answer that question, I would say "Yes". But nothing is wrong with your approach if you want it that way.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on level of the security you may want to apply. If the server's certificate is valid CA signed certificates it must applies enough security. Most of the online banking services relies on this kind of protection against man in middle attacks so it is de facto well enough. All benefits covered [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1117/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-self-signed-certificate-on-a-live-site).

In case you want to be extract secure you may go for extra layer of security on application level of the communication as the history knows 3rd party certificates to had been compromised. The story [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigiNotar).